# <script> require('renderer.js') </script> - does not connect the js file

Tags: javascript, html, electron, ipc, require

Using Electron, I'm trying to organize IPC between main and renderer. As instructions say I should add the script (see the title) to the index.html. But it doesn't look like it is loaded. Nothing in the rendeder.js gets executed.

It's in this tutorial https://www.brainbell.com/javascript/ipc-communication.html which is the most detailed one on the topic in the internet. Others just skip so much info in their articles that a learner simply can't reproduce it in the app.

I tried:

```
<script> 
    require('renderer.js')
</script>

<script>
    require('./renderer.js')
</script>

<script src='renderer.js'>
</script>
```

etc similar.

Comment: Are you working in `Electron 5` – if so, you need to set `nodeintergration: true` when you create the window.

Comment: Open devTools. Any console errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let me show what I do, maybe that will help.

Code to create a window. Note the `webPreferences` settings

```
app.on('ready', function () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    show: false,
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    backgroundColor: '#2C3E50',
    center: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      devTools: true
    }
  })
```

Without [devtools](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/application-debugging) you can not see error output or inspect content. There are other ways to open `devTools` through menu and keyboard commands.

Then, assuming you have installed the script or lib through `npm` you can just do the following without specifying a path, otherwise you will need a relative path

```
const THREE = require('three')
```

Comment: I suggest that for the present you skip using `require` and just link the "renderer.js" script in the html page. Have it at the bottom or use `defer`. There are lots of tutorials about `electron` – some better than others. Just try to learn one thing at a time. For example, this man's tutorials are very good: video [Main and renderer process communication in Electron](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7cCASOLdAQ). Related article: http://electron.rocks/different-ways-to-communicate-between-main-and-renderer-process/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem.

First, make sure when you launch the app, you turn on nodeIntegration:

```js
app.on('ready', _ => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        title: "My Electron App",
        backgroundColor: '#FFF',
        height: 800,
        width: 1200,
        center: true,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true // works on main window only
        }
    })
```

Then, reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070373/6501141).

Playing with multiple options, both using `require` and `src=` methods work. See below with additional inline comments.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- make sure you have the semicolon after the require -->
    <!-- and make sure NOT to include the .js extension -->
      <script>require('./renderer');</script>
    <!-- make sure you include the extension -->
      <script src="./renderer.js" ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Put HTML first to avoid blocking -->
    <!-- All same options as in head work here, but shouldn't block -->
    <!-- In addition, async and defer might do something -->
    <!-- async should run script asynchronously, and defer wait until DOM loads -->
      <script src="./renderer.js" async></script>
      <script src="./renderer.js" defer></script>
  </body>
  <!-- scripts put here seems intermittent which runs first -->
</html>
<!-- scripts put here seems intermittent which runs first -->
```

Some will block the HTML from loading until the script runs (I think if in the `head` tag, no matter what), while others seemed random whether the HTML would load before the script ran. I tested with an alert box in my `renderer.js`, which would block the window from showing the HTML rendering if it ran first.